# How can one test session features in helper modules in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a helper which has some logic for controlling the display of a partial :

```
module BannerHelper
  def show_add_friend_link?
    !current_page(friends_path) && !current_user.has_friends?
  end
end

require 'rails_helper'

describe BannerHelper do
  context 'when user has friends'
    it 'does not show the add friends link' do
      expect(helper.show_add_friend_link?).to eq false
    end
  end
end
```

I'm trying to create a test (using rspec 3.2) but current_user isn't defined. I have been able to use current_user from controller tests. current_user is defined in application_controller. Perhaps current_user shouldn't be referred to from a helper though I am not sure where to place this logic.

Comment: Please post the test code you've written so far.

Comment: Also, what version of RSpec?

Comment: I've included the info.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options.

1. Since the RSpec group that described an Helper mixes the helper module into itself, you can define the current_user as method inside the example.

   ```
   describe BannerHelper do
     context 'when user has friends'
       let(:current_user) { instance_double("User", has_friends: true) }
       it 'does not show the add friends link' do
         expect(show_add_friend_link?).to eq false
       end
     end
   end
   ```
2. Use dependency injection, and change the helper method to accept the `current_user` as parameter.

Comment: I get `undefined local variable or method 'current_user' for #<#<Class:0x00000008435488>:0x0000000842d738>`

if I remove `helper.` I then receive the error `You cannot use helpers that need to determine the current page unless your view context provides a Request object in a #request method`

Comment: Make sure the spec is tagged as `:type => :helper`, as per `rspec-rails` documentation. You are right, RSpec 3.x seems to suggest the use of `helper`.

Comment: As for `current_page`, the issue is exactly the one describe by the error. You either redefine it as well, or you provide a request context.

Comment: I'm unsure how to provide a request context. I know how it is done in controller helpers, using something like `get :index` but those have an implicitly associated path associated, is that right?

Comment: To clarify, 'current_user' does not work regardless of using helper. or not.

Comment: It should. In fact, the error you are experiencing was another. Make sure you are defining its value properly.

Comment: current_user is defined in the Application Controller, I've tried definining current_user in the test several different ways and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by abandoning RSpec's helper test features and instead testing helper modules within the controller test ecosystem. Doing so provides access to the `request` and `session` objects, as well as other helper methods.

Here is an example:

```
describe BannerHelper, type: :controller do
  controller(ApplicationController) do
    include BannerHelper
  end

  describe "#show_add_friend_link?" do
    context 'when user has friends'
      it 'does not show the add friends link' do
        allow(subject).to receive(:current_user).and_return(some_user)
        # note that instead of ^ mock you can also simply set needed session key as it is accessible.

         expect(subject.send(:show_add_friend_link?)).to eq false
      end
    end
  end
```

end